# When a rational series converges to an irrational number, can I operate on the sum of the rational series as I would a rational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I am working on a problem involving Diophantine approximation. For some irrational value $0<\alpha<1$, I construct an infinite series $S = x + \frac{x_1}{10} + \frac{x_2}{10^2} + \frac{x_2}{10^3} + ... $ that converges to $\alpha$ where $x$ is the integer part of $\alpha$, and $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ denote the decimal values of $\alpha$. By fraction addition, we can determine the partial sum of S as $S_p = \frac{10^{p-1}(x) + 10^{p-2}(x_1)+ ... + x_p}{10^{p-1}}$. Let us define a number $\psi$ that for finite value $k$, $\psi>k$. In a sense, $\psi$ is transfinite. Define m as $$lim_{p\to\psi}   \space S_p=m$$ Can I treat m as a rational number and operate on it as I would a rational number? (e.g. reduce numerator & denominator, compare it to a unit fraction, etc.)

Comment: Isn‘t $m=\alpha$ ? Then of course $m$ is not rational.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Well, m isn't exactly equal to $\alpha$ since the limit approaches $\psi$ instead of infinity. Certainly, the gap between $\alpha$ and m is infinitesimal, but in this case, my question is whether m can be operated on as a rational number in terms of reducing it and comparing it to another fraction.

Comment: I don't believe your limit is defined or, if it is defined, then it is just $\alpha$.  What's $\psi$?

Comment: I have never heard of a transfinite partial sum. Is that a thing? If $\psi$ is not $\omega$, then for there to be the limit above, wouldn't there have to be a partial sum $S_{\omega}$? And if so, doesn't the definition of $S_p$ given above mean that to evaluate $S_{\omega}$ you would need to evaluate $10^{\omega - 1}$?

Comment: Are you doing nonstandard analysis? If so, you can let $\psi$ be an infinite hypernatural, and then you don't need to take a limit; just let $m=S_\psi$. If not, then $\psi$ doesn't make much sense. Either way, something's a bit off here.